# Function for Shapiro Test

Tags: r, function, statistics

I am trying to write a function to run a shapiro test for multiple columns in my data frame. I tried using the following code but it keeps returning this error.
I have made sure that the relevant columns are numeric.

```
fun1<- function(x){
  shapiro.test(names(data)[22:31])
}
```

this is the error I am getting

```
Error in shapiro.test(names(TBI)[22:31]) : is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your intent, you want to run the shapiro test on a dataframe `data` and columns `22:31`.  Then you should be able to generate a list of test results with `lapply`

```
stests <- lapply(data[, 22:31], function(x) shapiro.test(x))
```

Note that a dataframe is a special type of list and you can reference a subset of dataframe columns.

BTW, `names(data)[22:31]` returns a character vector of the column names, not the actual column content.

Comment: thank you so so much, that worked perfectly!

Comment: Great, can you uptick the answer?  Thanks.